# Should rotors be replaced every time brake pads/discs are?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor

Someone told me once that new brake pads/discs last much less if they are installed on old rotors, i.e. that an old rotor will wear a new brake refill much faster than a brand new one because of the settled residue on it.  An alternative is to clean the residue by some sort of grinding/polishing but I heard that requires a lathe, which I don't have.

Is it a good idea to replace rotors every time brake pads/discs are replaced?

This is supposed to be a make/model agnostic question but my truck is a 2007 4WD V6 Tacoma, if that matters.  The front brakes are pads, the rear are discs.

Comment: by "warped disc" do you mean a "warped rotor" ?